# fstream, to write ,then read, then write, but last write is failed,i don't know the reason

Tags: c++

```
fstream fs("f.txt", fstream::in | fstream::out | fstream::trunc);
if(fs)
{
    string str = "45464748";
    fs << str;

    fs.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    int i = -1;
    fs >> i;
    cout << i << endl;

    fs.seekp(0, ios::beg);

    i = 0x41424344;
    fs << i;

    fs.close();
}
```

f.txt content is "45464748",but I should understand it's content is "‭1094861636‬". I don't the reason, please help me.

Comment: Does `cout << i << endl;` print `45464748`?

Comment: yes, but next write is failed

Comment: Which compiler? Which Standard (C++11, C++14, ...)? Can you check the different bits (eofbit, failbit, badbit) at the different places?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stream state has its eof bit set by the previous read, so the write has no effect. Clear the stream state before the write.

```
void ftest()
{
  std::fstream fs("f.txt", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
  if(fs)
  {
    std::cout << "A: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    std::string str = "45464748";
    fs << str;
    std::cout << "B: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    fs.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::cout << "C: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    int i = -1;

    // THIS read sets the EOF bit.
    fs >> i;

    std::cout << "D: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    fs.seekp(0, std::ios::beg);
    std::cout << "E: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    i = 0x41424344;
    std::cout << "F: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    fs << "not written";
    fs.clear ();
    std::cout << "G: " << (fs.eof() ? "eof" : "neof") << std::endl;
    fs << i;
    fs.close();
  }
}
```

Output:

```
A: neof
B: neof
C: neof
D: eof
45464748
E: eof
F: eof
G: neof
```

File contents:

```
1094861636
```

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/seekp/ says "Notice that the function will work even if the eofbit flag is set before the call, but it will not modify it.". And I don't understand why a write should fail at end of file!?

Comment: You can do the seekp before the clear if you like, and it will work, as the documentation you quoted says. But the write will not work. The reason it fails is that those are the rules -- see the doc for ostream::put and then ostream::sentry.